# How to calculate t-value, given degrees of freedom and $\alpha$.

Tags: probability, statistics

While solving problems, we can look up physical t-tables or use a statistical analysis software like R to calculate t-values.

But how do we actually calculate these values ? 
What is the algorithm behind it ?
How does the widget in this website (http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc3/calc.aspx?id=10 ) calculates it ?

Answer (score 3):

I think the down-votes are pretty harsh - this is a perfectly sensible question.

t-values are derived from [Student's t-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-distribution) which has the probability density function shown on that page (and which I am not going to recreate). The distribution arises when one samples a population of unknown mean and variance.

The t-value is calculated by setting the $P(X=t)$ for 1 sided or $P(X=\frac{t}{2})$ for 2 sided and solving for $x$.